# Rails 3.1 and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I've the following code:

in my view

```
<div id="flash_notice" style="display: none;"></div>
<%= link_to "Vote", {:controller=>"your_controller_name", :action => 'vote',:id=>@warehouse.id, :vote=>true}, :remote=> true, :method => :put %>
```

In my controller

```
def vote
  @warehouse = Warehouse.find(params[:id])
  @warehouse.update_attribute(:vote, params[:vote])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In my routes file

```
resources :your_controller_name do
  collection do
   put 'vote'
  end
end
```

and this is "vote.js.erb"

```
$("#flash_notice").html("You have voted successfully");
$("#flash_notice").show("slow");
```

Now, I want that when 'flash notice' has displayed, another things (such as icons,html code and so on) has displayed to and it should be permanent. I explain better: I've a table and I've a 'flash_notice" `<div>` for each table items. I want that when I click on  'Vote' referred to an item, I must use something to remember me that I've just clicked on this item and I cannot click again.

Comment: format your code please ( i do it for you )

Answer (score 0):

You could unbind the click event for the voting link after it's been clicked. Or, if you want to wait until your `vote.js.erb` has executed before disabling the click event, you might have the voting link pass a parameter that identifies itself uniquely to the controller (e.g. `?vote_id=1`), then in your `vote.js.erb` you will have access to `params[:vode_id]` so you can disable the click event for the link from there.